# Why do either of these rethrown exceptions create a compiler error?

Tags: java, exception, throws

Why does `throw outerE;` generate a compilation error?  I know that `throw e;` should not generate a compiler error because of the [precise rethrow feature.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html)

They're the same `Exception` object, but one is scoped inside the `catch` block only and one is scoped outside the try-catch block.

Shouldn't neither of these generate a compiler error? Or, at least, both behave the same way?

```
static void preciseRethrowTest()
{
    Exception outerE;
    try
    {

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        outerE = e;

        // Compilation error here. Unhandled exception type Exception
        // throw outerE; 

        throw e; // No compiler error
    }
}
```

I'm using Java 1.8.0_51. (Precise rethrow is introduced in Java 7)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method has no `throws` declarations.

The compiler is now smart enough to determine that your `try` block cannot throw any checked exceptions. Therefore, any exceptions caught and bound to the `Exception` parameter in your `catch` block must be unchecked. Since they are unchecked, you can rethrow them at your leisure (and they won't require a `throws` declaration).

Here, you are attempting to reassign

```
outerE = e;
// Compilation error here. Unhandled exception type Exception
// throw outerE;
```

and rethrow the exception through a different variable. The compiler doesn't go that far to figure out what the value in `outerE` is. It can be the exception in you caught or it can be something else. The compiler play it safe and prevents you from doing it.

Consider code like

```
if (Math.random() < 0.5) 
    outerE = e;
else 
    outerE = new IOException("nope");
throw outerE;
```

There's no way for the compiler to know whether the `Exception` value stored in `outerE` is the unchecked exception you caught or some other, potentially checked, exception you assigned from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the catch block cannot be reached by checked exceptions; the compiler is smart enough to realize this.

Consider this:

```
public class RethrowTest {
  static void preciseRethrowTest() {
    Exception outerE;
    try {
      throw new Exception();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      outerE = e;

      // Compilation error here. Unhandled exception type Exception
      // throw outerE;

      throw e; // Now a compiler error *is* generated.
    }
  }
}
```

This *does* throw a compiler error, because the code can be reached by a checked exception now.